# using pipewire, br connection profile unavailable

Tags: bluetooth, pipewire

using pipewire, br connection profile unavailable
i am trying to connect my boat headphones to xubuntu22. the issue is this error while pairing/connecting. when i switch back to pulseaudio it again is working fine, but in pulseaudio i am not able to use the MIC in my headphones so i thought id use pipewire...

```
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              mehul@Lenovo 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           ------------ 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Xubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Host: 90LX0091IN ideacentre 510S-07I 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Kernel: 5.15.0-27-generic 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Uptime: 30 mins 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Packages: 2931 (dpkg), 8 (flatpak),  
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   Resolution: 1024x768 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   DE: Xfce 4.16 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM: Xfwm4 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   WM Theme: Greybird 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Theme: Greybird-dark [GTK2/3] 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/ 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       CPU: Intel i3-9100 (4) @ 3.600GHz 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Gra 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           Memory: 1854MiB / 3818MiB 
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`
```

Answer (score 3):

try to install `libspa-0.2-bluetooth` and reboot your system
this fix the issue in kubuntu 22.10